# StreamProvider - Flutter - How to update stream/s on user login

Tags: ios, flutter, mobile

I am building an app with the below structure to get a list of transactions that the user has added/performed.

[App Screens Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oYs0T.png)

Above the Material app in main.dart I have a streamProvider which is dependent on the Firebase UID(shown in the code snippet).

Anticipated behaviour: Whenever user logs in they should be getting a stream of transactiosn for thier UID.

Actual behaviour: Whenever the user logs in they still see the transactions from the 'someID' collection even though they have logged in.

```
var dbTransactionRef = db
        .collection('users')
        .doc(_auth.currentUser == null ? 'someId' : _auth.currentUser.uid)
        .collection('transactions');


StreamProvider<List<T.Transaction>>.value(
          initialData: [T.Transaction()],
          value: dbTransactionRef.snapshots().map((snapshot) => snapshot.docs
              .map((document) => T.Transaction.fromJSON(document.data()))
              .toList()),
        ),
```

It seems like the stream is not updating on login of a user. Please could you help me to update the code to get the anticipated behaviour? Thanks!

Comment: How do you detect changes in authentication state? Where do you setup this `StreamProvider` in your widget tree?

Comment: Hi Peter! I have set up the stream provider above the Material App Widget. I have an AuthService.dart file which checks for the auth state changes and provides a stream of User objects.